# Is there a framework available to collect user feedback on an SWT GUI?

Tags: swt, bug-reporting, user-feedback

After 2 years of development, our Eclipse RCP desktop application is finally finished. The last step in development is to allow the client to provide feedback on the wording and labels in the application.

There will be about 10 people providing feedback, but the client is willing to consolidate this before sending this to us for implementation.

My first idea is to provide a Google Form which requires them to upload a screenshot and to precisely specify where the text to be changed is located. I am now wondering whether a framework exists to do this automatically (i.e. press 'CTRL+ALT' and you can automatically draw a box around the offending text in the application.

**In short: Are there any user feedback tools specifically designed to collect feedback on the wording in a GUI?**

Answer (score 1):

Mylyn includes some facilities to do (almost) exactly this. In a standard Eclipse, try `Help` -> `Report Bug or Enhancement`...

You use various `org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks...` extension points to specify things like product, area and bug template.

Comment: Report "Bug or Enhancement" is useful when collecting information on the platform and immediately filling a bug report. It does not have any graphical capabilities though: does not take a screenshot and does not allow you to highlight the specific area of the GUI where the error is located.

Comment: Once you have submitted a bug report, you can attach a screenshot to the issue directly in the Attachments section...